# Images not stacking properly

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I'm using jquery masonry and having trouble getting images/posts to stack properly (see attached image).

The problem is that there is too much white space/ gap between the posts/images.

How can I fix this?

Thanks,

Faisal

**INDEX.HTML.ERB**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .item {
   width: 200px;
   margin: 8px;
   float: left;
   border: 1px solid #999999; 
   background-color: #F7F7F7; 
   -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
   padding: 6px;
   color: black;
   }

</style>
<div id="container">
<br />
<br />
<br />
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="item">
<%= post.body %>
<br />
<%= post.title %> 
<br />
<i>RSVP -- <%= post.job %>.</i>
<br />
<i>Created <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago.</i>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).load() { 
$('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.box',
  columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
  return containerWidth / 5;
  });
});
</script>
<% end %>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Update your question with your actual HTML, not the ERB template

Comment: +1 for @MichaelRobinson; a JSFiddle would also help.

Comment: thanks guys- here's the jsfiddle page link: http://jsfiddle.net/HSK8E/ let me know if it helps..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSfiddle would be good, also try using the

`$(window).load(function() {`

as egasimus pointed out...

`$(document).ready(function()`

won't work, but the (function() bit is the one I'd try first. You can 'fiddle' with `gutterWidth` as well (masonry).

### UPDATE:

I've forked the jsfiddle you made, cleaned up some of the code (a lot of redundant javascript etc) and got it to work. I've used the suggestions at masonry etc, but should make sense. Check out the fiddle for working version:http://jsfiddle.net/8KHAh/11/

```
$(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.item',
    columnWidth : 226
  });
});
```

Make sure you use similar CSS or adjust the `columnWidth` to adjust for padding etc.

Comment: Just saw your edits, tried it and it works!!! You just made my week. I spent over 20 hours trying to fix it. THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: Cool thanks for the up-vote. I finally have enough points here at stack to be useful :)

Answer (score 1):

I just had my first look at jQuery Masonry, and, from what this looks like, maybe the plugin hasn't run at all? This usually happens to me when I have a syntax error in my code. Your JS looks a little sketchy, and, hmm... gotcha! Use this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
      return containerWidth / 5;
    }
  });
});
```

That's got to work.

Here's why proper indentation is important -- if you had it, the problem (and solution) would be almost immediately obvious to you. First, you were calling:

```
$(window).load() { /* your code goes here */ }
```

Those are two completely separate statements, virtually the same as:

```
$(window).load(); /* your code goes here */
```

You need to pass an anonymous function as the parameter to `.load()`, like this:

```
$(window).load ( function() { /* your code goes here */ } )
```

Also, you had a semicolon in your settings object, after defining the `columnWidth` function -- the same as if you had typed

```
{
   name1: 'value1',
   name2: 'value2'; // <-- SYNTAX ERROR
   name3: 'value3', // it's okay to leave a trailing comma, though
}
```

That one always gets me, too, but it's much easier to see with proper indentation.

The conclusion: teach yourself good *indentation*. Also, use your browser's *JS console* to check for syntax errors; it alone helps tremendously in figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: the JS error is fixed now, but the original problem -- too much white space between the posts -- is still there. my screen still looks like the screenshot posted above. what should i do?

Comment: @hikmatyar I presume the JS console doesn't say anything, either? Well, what I posted was as much as I could deduct from what you've given; we're probably going to need a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code to figure out everything else.

Comment: i added jsfiddle; u can also see the live website at www.faisalandsamreen.com/posts

Comment: Yup, the JS console gives me the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'`

Comment: Looking at your JS, it isn't too clear what you're doing there, but it seems you may have commented out your jQuery? Also, the error message suggests that your script is trying to use the `.on()` method, which doesn't exist until jQuery 1.7 -- try using the latest version?

Comment: i updated to jquery 1.7.2 and don't see any js errors now...except for a minor one that seems unrelated to the problem at hand. here is the new JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QCsVC/  let me know if u see what i'm doing wrong...i also deployed updated code to www.faisalandsamreen.com/posts if u want to see it there. thanks!!!

Comment: You don't need to put `<script>` tags in the JS field :)

Comment: Well, to be fair and square, I'm not sure what's going on there. You have a script that does the same thing over and over again after every `div class=item`. You only need to do that once; move all `script` tags to the bottom of the `body`, remove the two commented out versions of jQuery from your `js` file, and make sure you're not coding by copy/paste.

Answer (score -1):

Im not familiar with masonry but i show you have a 8px margin and a 6px padding. I would start by trying to reduce those, maybe two or three pixels. If that didn't give me anything i would add a border to that class and find out exactly what it was affecting